# How do I align two dojo widgets next to each other?

Tags: css, layout, dojo

Warning, this is possibly the easiest possible question ever asked here.
I have a form like this:

```
  <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" data-dojo-attach-point="loginPane" data-dojo-props="title: 'Login'">
    <div data-dojo-type="hotplate.hotDojoWidgets.AlertBar" data-dojo-attach-point="loginAlertBar"></div>
    <form data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Form" data-dojo-attach-point="loginForm" method="POST">
      <label for="${id}_login">Login</label>
      <input name="login" id="${id}_login" data-dojo-attach-point="login" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.ValidationTextBox" data-dojo-props="required:true"/>
      <label for="${id}_password">Password</label>
      <input type="password" name="password" id="${id}_password0" data-dojo-attach-point="password" data-dojo-type="hotplate.hotDojoAuth.ValidationPassword" />
      <input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="${id}_remember" data-dojo-attach-point="remember" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.CheckBox" />
      <label for="${id}_checkbox">Remember login</label>    
      <input type="submit" data-dojo-attach-point="loginButton" data-dojo-type="hotplate.hotDojoWidgets.BusyButton" label="Login!" />
    </form>
    <div data-dojo-attach-event="onclick:_onRecoverClick">Recover your password</div>
  </div>
```

It's a pretty basic form. Now, what I want to do is simple: I simply would like the label "Remember login" to be NEXT to the checkbox. As simple as that.
I would also like a little more space between the password field and the checkbox.

Now, what is the *easiest*, *neatest* way of doing this? (Please do it just adding "style=" within this template, I will add it to the CSS properly).

I tried `display:inline` for the checkbox. However, it ends up not displaying at all, as Dojo seems to place it on the far left hand side of the page (?).

I will need to create a "new customer" form, and I would love to be able to place things next to each other and create neater layouts, rather than the usual one-field-per-line form.

BONUS QUESTION: what's the *easiest* way to get a border to appear around a group of widgets? Something classy.

Thanks!

Merc.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2009/02/25/styling-dijit-form-elements/) helps a little? And to your bonus question (awesome gimmik btw.): in a form, this is usually done using a `fieldset`, or do i get your question wrong?

Comment: To be honest, I'd just use a table.  I guess lots of people would bork at the thought of laying out a form using a table but I think it satisfies the concept of tabular data?  Most of us remember the bad old days of table layouts on websites and I agree that, that was horrid.  Tables however, do have their place and I normally allow myself to use them for forms as long as th and label tags are used correctly (alongside a table summary).  It's a bit of a grey area, is a form, tabular data?  Certainly, it is collecting tabular data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As posted in my comment above, I'd just use a table as I think this is fine for a form.  However, many people would disagree with me.

If you want to avoid tables you could place the checkbox inside the **<label>**.  You can bind a control to a label, either by using the *for* attribute or placing the control inside the **<label>**.

- See [w3 tutorial on label use](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp)

Hence, you could change:

```
<input
    type="checkbox" name="remember" id="${id}_remember"
    data-dojo-attach-point="remember"
    data-dojo-type="dijit.form.CheckBox" />
<label for="${id}_checkbox">Remember login</label>
```

to:

```
<label style="margin-left:10px">
    <input
        type="checkbox" name="remember"
        data-dojo-attach-point="remember"
        data-dojo-type="dijit.form.CheckBox"
    />Remember login
</label>
```

This should place the label to the right of the checkbox and bind the label to the checkbox.  I've also, added a margin-left to the label so that space is created between your password field and the checkbox.