# How do I use html labels with dijit/form widgets?

Tags: dojo, dijit.form

Ok, so I'm building an app using Dojo 1.8, and I have a custom widget with a template similar to this...

```
<div>
  <label for="tag">Select something: </label>
  <select id="tag"
      data-dojo-attach-point="tag"
      data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Select">
    <option value="0">option 0</option>
    <option value="1">option 1</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

However, when the template gets rendered, the widget defines a new id, which makes the  tag useless. I've tried googling this, but all my searches just direct to the Dojo documentation since they have attributes called labels but have nothing to do with the HTML label tag.

What is the proper why to do this?

Answer (score 1):

In the situation you describe, you can simply place the label around your **<select>** and dispose with the for/id attributes. see Stackoverflow question:

- [How do I align two dojo widgets next to each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13715345/how-do-i-align-two-dojo-widgets-next-to-each-other/13720865#13720865), also see: [w3 tutorial on label use](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp)

Also, if you want to actually use Ids in a widget template, see:

- [How do I create unique IDs in a Dojo widget template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11182103/how-do-i-create-unique-ids-in-a-dojo-widget-templateList)

Using ids directly (ie. hard-coding them, not assigning them on-the-fly as in the above link) is not encouraged.  The reason for this is that a template is meant to used over and over again in the creation of widgets.

In theory, it could be used to create multiple widgets on one page. Hence, in that situation you would have an id conflict.  Each HTML id, on any one page, needs to be unique.

Comment: Thanks for the links. I like how wrapping the form element with the label cleans up the code, and shows a strong relationship between the two elements. Also, you are completely right about the 'id' within templates issue. Momentary lapse in judgement on my part. All that said though, my problem still persists. I believe it's a result of Dojo replacing the Select with a table based widget, which simulates the behavior of a Select. After being rendered, the label points to a table vs a Select element. It appears that there should be somewhere in the widget to configure label behavior.

Comment: Did a little more digging, and I found that the form widgets that inherit from dijit/form/TextBox (ComboBox, FilteringSelect, etc) behave as expected, since TextBox leverages the <input> tag. Whereas, dijit/form/Select doesn't leverage <select>.